# Why am I able to access the view inside onNext method RxAndroid inspite of not set observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())?

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I am researching into `RxJava`/`RxAndroid`. I decided to create `Observable` via `Observable.fromCallable` method because of it gives us two important things:

> 1. The code for creating the emitted value is not run until someone subscribes to the Observerable
> 2. The creation code can be run on a different thread.

I have wrote the sample as below:

```
private void testObservableFromCallable() {
    Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return "Hello";
        }
    });

    Subscription subscription = stringObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {
                    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    textView.setText(s);
                }
            });
}
```

Every things are ok. It work fine and log tag show thread name is `main`. It means `onNext()` method be called on `mainThread()` and `textView` be accessed properly.

Now what am I confusing is when I remove this line `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` or just change it to `observeOn(Schedulers.io())`. Both of two cases the log tag show thread name is `RxIoScheduler`. That is not main thread, but the app compile with no error and `textView` show the text "Hello" on the screen.

Anyone help me explain why am I able to access to the view outside main thread?.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Already answered by ChristianB
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65502555/why-onnext-is-updating-textview-though-observeonschedulars-io-on-a-differ/65529843#65529843

Answer (score 1):

The framework usually does not do anything to check that you're really on the main thread. As a caller, it's your responsibility.

Some but not all UI widget access on non-main thread lead to a crash. Here you're being "lucky" that the thread problem goes undetected with your method call.

Comment: You're right, It should be my responsibility. I am just trying to test as much case as I possible find to know how the system do. That's the way I am learning.

Comment: I have just found that there is a log cat like that:  `Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` It will disappear if I set  `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) `. I suppose that when have not set thread for Observer object, both of Observerble and Observer are run on main thread. That's why the log cat above is throw.  I know you are expert. Do you have any idea?